# How do I enforce a minimum value on a Enthought Traits/UI Float trait?

Tags: enthought, traitsui

I'm using the Enthought Traits/UI system and would like to enforce a minimum value on a Float trait, which appears in the GUI and is editable by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Range` trait instead. `Range(low=minimum_value)`